# Paste MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection object in Reply email

Tags: outlook

---

"Original" is an email in Inbox and has a table with last column unfilled.
How do i paste "oElColl" in "Reply" ???

---

```
Dim Reply As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Original As Outlook.MailItem

Set Original = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)

Set Reply = Original.ReplyAll
Reply.Subject = "RE: " & Original.Subject
Reply.Display 

Dim oHTML As MSHTML.HTMLDocument: Set oHTML = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim oElColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
With oHTML
.Body.innerHTML = Original.HTMLBody
Set oElColl = .getElementsByTagName("table")
End With
```

' Code to fill the last column in oElColl

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy 100% foolproof way to load HTML into an HTMLDocument object synchronously. I very much doubt that HTMLDocument.Body.innerHTML = Original.HTMLBody would work. You can use HTMLDocument.write, but it can hang for some HTML messages.

Try to use MailItem.GetInspector().WordEditor to retrieve the Word document object and use it instead.